# How to check naming conventions violations in Notepad++?

Tags: naming-conventions, notepad++

We use Notepad++ for Java coding. We need to follow some project specific naming conventions.
For instance, `String` should starts with an S, and `Map`, M.
In Notepad++, how can I highlight if any mismatches in the naming convention are there, while coding?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend maintaining your current convention for syntax highlighting, but not for style checks.

Use checkstyle with your own custom rules, and consider adding it to your build process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please can you tell me in details the steps for highlighting in notepad++? How can I set my own naming convention rules and use it in notepad++?

Comment: You can set syntax highlighting as per the GUI: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Languages, but checkstyle seems like a better option for coding standards, due to its great fexibility and popularity in Java projects.